# JMeter JMS Point to Point not returning correct response

Tags: jms, jmeter, activemq-classic

JMeter Version: 2.10  .
ActiveMQ 5.9

I have a point to point JMeter script that successfully places a message on a queue. This messaged is then consumed, transformed and placed on a different queue. When I test just a request method (from jmeter), the message is successfully submitted, transformed and returned to the out queue, however when I configure JMeter to consume the response on the out queue, it shows the original request message payload as the response.

Here is my JMeter script details:

1. JMS Resources

   - QueueuConnectionFactory: ConnectionFactory
   - JNDI Name Request Queue: Q.REQ
   - JNDI Name Reply Queue: Q.RPL
2. Message Properties

   - Communication Style: Request Response
   - Use alternate fields for message correlation: Use Request Message ID (ticked)
   - Content: (XML Payload)
3. JNDI Properties

   - InitialContextFactory: org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
   - queue.Q.REQ: message.in
   - queue.Q.RPL: message.out
   - java.naming.security.principal: admin
   - java.naming.security.credentials: admin
4. Properties

   - Provider URL: tcp://localhost:61616

I've also tried a few different combinations such as removing the reply queue and specifying a JMSReplyTo as well as manually specifying a JMSCorrelationID. If someone could point me in the right direction or even provide a working jmeter proj example, it would be much appreciated. I also used this guide: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-point-to-point-test-plan.html to help build my test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having spoke to a few people, this is a known issue and I haven't found a suitable workaround for this issue right now.

Currently I have had to use the JMeter JMS Pub/Sub Samplers to get this to work properly. If I hear back from the user group I will update this answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you're missing `Q.REQ` and `Q.RPL` definition in **JNDI Properties** section. They should go along with InitialContextFactory bit.

See [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter) guide for more details.

Comment: Sorry updated my typo. Both Q.REQ and Q.PRL are specified in the JNDI properties as: queue.Q.REQ: message.in, queue.Q.RPL: message.out. Also , thanks for the guide but it pretty much replicates the guide on the jmeter site.